# Toggle DIV element

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, this seems to be a easy question but I'm not able to get it.

I have index.php and find.php in my project.
In index.php, I'm showing results of list-group items as follows

```
   <div id="showDetails">
           
   </div>


   <div id="showList">
           //All my list-group items are listed here
   </div>
```

My Ajax returning the list-group as follows

```
function funcReadRecord() {
    var readrecord1 = "readrecord1";
    var sometext = $('#SNOW_INC').val();

    $.ajax({
      url : "find.php",
      type : 'post' ,
      data : { readrecord1 : readrecord1,
        sometext : sometext } ,
        success : function(data, status){
          $('#showList').html(data);
        }
      });

    }
```

Now, I'm returning the values as a HTML link so it looks like this

```
   <div id="showList">
           <a href="#">data 1</a>
           <a href="#">data 2</a>
           <a href="#">data 3</a>
   </div>
```

What I want is when I click `data 1` link, I want to show `showDetails` div with `data 1` populated. Then when I click `data 2` link, it changes to `data 2` in `showDetails`.

How do I do that?

Probably the information I've provided is not enough but feel free to ask and I'll provide more.

Comment: chec [link](https://codepen.io/noor007/pen/qBZJvBr).. do you want this ?

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor, not really. I want the div to show when I click the data link

Comment: can you check again [link](https://codepen.io/noor007/pen/qBZJvBr) ..

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to add a [click handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) to each item that calls a function, passing in the id of the item you want to display.

Within that function, fetch the data for the given item and show it.

```js
function showData(which) {
  console.log(`fetch data ${which} here and show it in the data div.`);
  document.getElementById('showData').innerHTML = `show data ${which}`
  return false; // prevents navigation on the clicked link
}
```

```html
<div id="showList">
  <a onclick="showData(1)" href="#">data 1</a>
  <a onclick="showData(2)" href="#">data 2</a>
  <a onclick="showData(3)" href="#">data 3</a>
 </div>

<div id="showData"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, this seems more like it, but I'm quite a beginner. Where should I write this? index or find page?

Comment: Where to put it is a question with no single right answer, and I don't know enough about your project to have an opinion on it. For starters put it in the same place as your `funcReadRecord` function.